# How to add inline comment in editor.js

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I've integrated [editor.js](https://editorjs.io/). I wanted to add an inline comment feature to it. anyone who can guide me through it.

Comment: The same feature they are talking about here: https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/issues/1446 ?

Comment: yes the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Not available, There is a feature-request in [GitHub](https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/issues/1446) that still open, so likely you will have to wait until the feature get implemented or to develop your own feature in the Library.